# Converting a flat data to LIST DICT tree

Tags: python, tree

For my project, I need to list all products and send them as a nested JSON for my app. I have created code to do so, but I do not understand where my logic has failed me. Following is my code.

The flat data I have is like `type`, `category`, `sub`, `name`, `price`, etc. and so on.

Since Type, Cat, Sub are in a single string, I parse them with `re.search`, the result being stored in `parse`.

In my python `main`, I retrieve all records, and in a `for each row in rows`, I call :

```
    product_list = add_on_tree(parse, product_list, p_dict, 1)
```

where product_list is `[]` initially, p_dict is a dict like : {name:'', price:'',... etc}

```
def add_on_tree(parse, plist, pdict, i):
    if parse.group(i):
        listCheck = ""
        """
        empty   ==>> plist is empty
        match   ==>> plist[i].type =  parse.group(i)
        nomatch ==>> plist[i].type != parse.group(i)
        """
        if plist==[]:
            listCheck = "empty"
        else:
            listCheck = "nomatch"
            for l in plist:
                if l["type"]==parse.group(i):
                    listCheck = "match"

        if listCheck in ["empty", "nomatch"]:
            newdict = {}
            newdict["type"] = parse.group(i)
            newdict["sub"] = []
            newdict["leaves"] = []
            try:
                if parse.group(i+1):
                    sublist = add_on_tree(parse, [], pdict, i+1 )
                    newdict["sub"] = sublist
                    plist.append(newdict)
                    return plist
            except:
                newdict["leaves"].append(pdict)
                plist.append(newdict)
                return plist
        else:
            for p in plist:
                if p["type"]==parse.group(i):
                    try:
                        if parse.group(i+1):
                            sublist = add_on_tree(parse, p["sub"], pdict, i+1)
                            p["sub"] = sublist
                            return plist
                    except:
                        p["leaves"].append(pdict)
                        return plist
                else:
                    p["sub"] = ["Error Somewhere", p["type"]]
                    return plist
```

**Required Tree Structure**

```
 [
   {
     type     : 'car entertainment',
     sub      : [
                  {
                    type     : 'Head Unit',
                    sub      : [
                                 {
                                   type     : 'USB',
                                   sub      : [],
                                   products : [
                                                {
                                                  name : '',
                                                  url  : '',
                                                  price: ''
                                                }
                                              ]
                                 }
                               ],
                    products : []
                  },
                  {},
                  {}
                ],
     products : []
   },
   {
     type     : 'home entertainment',
     sub      : [
                  {
                    type     : 'Audio',
                    sub      : [],
                    products : [
                                 {
                                   name:,
                                   url:,
                                   type:
                                 },
                                 {
                                   name:,
                                   url:,
                                   type:
                                 }
                               ]
                  },
                  {},
                  {}
                ],
     products : []
   }
 ]
```

**What I get :**

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "leaves": [], 
      "sub": [
        "Error Somewhere", 
        "Car Entertainment"
      ], 
      "type": "Car Entertainment"
    }, 
    {
      "leaves": [], 
      "sub": [
        {
          "leaves": [], 
          "sub": [
            {
              "leaves": [
                {
                  "desc": "", 
                  "image": "", 
                  "name": "", 
                  "price": 25000.0, 
                  "url": ""
                }
              ], 
              "sub": [], 
              "type": "Smartest"
            }
          ], 
          "type": "Smart"
        }
      ], 
      "type": "Home Entertainment"
    }
  ]
}
```

In `flask`, I use `jsonify(products=product_list)`, which explains the outermost dict `products`.

**Additional info**

1. I am using a `mysql` DB, and it has only four records.
2. When I use `pdb`, I find that where 'error somewhere' is appended, printing p["type"] returns p['type']
3. If I change

   ```
   product_list = add_on_tree(parse, product_list, p_dict, 1)
   ```

   to

   ```
   product_list = add_on_tree(parse, [], p_dict, 1)
   ```

   the last row is rendered correctly. This causes me to think that my logic works well when the list is empty, but fails when it has to insert into existing structures.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Update - Solution**

As @matt pointed out the error was in :

```
                else:
                    p["sub"] = ["Error Somewhere", p["type"]]
                    return plist
```

The following change got rid of the error:

```
                else:
                    return plist
```

**PS** - I have since replaced nesting with flat data. Nesting (processing) should be left to the end applications. Otherwise it creates more headaches than it solves.

Comment: What is the original text you are parsing with re?

Comment: It is something like "Home:Smart:Smartest".

Parsed with `parse = re.search("(.*):(.*):(.*)", product[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is pretty convoluted, but I think I see the immediate issue:

```
else:
    p["sub"] = ["Error Somewhere", p["type"]]
    return plist
```

You are erroring if the first item in the list doesn't match the type you are searching for. Instead you should error if you iterate through the list without finding your desired type.

Try putting your error check after the loop.

Comment: Thanks!. That was the error!. I was thinking wrong. I removed the unnecessary substitution and i got the Tree

Comment: Is there any better solution to unflatten data of this sort?